# Avoid showing new model itself

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, store

I have got a form to create a new Model called Route. In the form is a select field, called takeover, showing all Routes and the user can select one to get an relationship to the selected Route. 
My problem is that the newly created Route is even selectable in the select field, because I simply return 'this.get('store').findAll('routes');'.
How can I remove the new Model from the selection, because it is not possible to create a relationship to itself.

In the Route I create a empty Model and then the user can modify the attributes withhin the form:

```
//route.js
model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('route', {});
  },
```

Template:

```
//route.hbs
<form>
//some fields
//and a select-component:
{{my-select
    selected=model.takeover
    options=routes
}}
</form>
```

the routes wich I give to the selectable options also in the route:

```
//route.js
 routes: Ember.computed(function () {
    return this.get('store').findAll('route');
  }).readOnly(),
```

So routes are all routes including the new model. But it shouldnt be able to select the model itself so I have to remove it out of routes. How can I do it?

Comment: you can add an extra boolean to your model. For example isSelectable.
When you return your store use filterBy('isSelectable', true) to only show the routes you want.

Comment: this want work in my case. i want to show all routes, but not the route wich was created . I updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
routes: Ember.computed(function () {
    return this.get('store').findAll('route').then(function(result){
     return result.filterBy('isNew', false);
    });
  }).readOnly(),
```

Update:

If possible don't have `route` or `routes` as your route name and computed property name.

In route.js

```
model(){
 return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  newRecord: this.store.createRecord('route', {}),
  routes : this.get('store').findAll('route').then(function(result){
     return result.filterBy('isNew', false);
    }),
  });
},
setupController(controller,model){
 this._super(...arguments);
 controller.set('NewRecordModel',model.newRecord);
 controller.set('routes',model.routes);
}
```

and in route.hbs template,

```
{{my-select
    selected=NewRecordModel.takeover
    options=routes
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, this work but I am not sure if it is good ember-practise

Comment: findAll always return live arrays, so filtering according to our need is good ember practise and it can be done anywhere(inside route and controller) depends on the use case. in your case I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Why you use the setupController hook? I could also use the new record by 'model.newRecord.takeover' and 'model.routes', or?

Comment: just renaming it to make it simple one that's either ways is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed property to simply filter by records that are not new

```
routes: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'isNew', false)
```

`isNew` is true for models that haven't been persisted yet (i.e. you have `.save()` it yet).  You can read more about it here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew

I would keep the request to the store separate from the CP that filters the list. That way we have the logic that makes a request to our backend/store in the model hook (where it should be), then result is sent to our controller, which is where our CP for filtering can live.

*Edit in response to comment:*

### The "Ember way"

Typically, Ember wants requests to your backend to live in the route file. It is built to have access to the store and comes equipped with async error handling.  You would typically request this in your model hook:

```
// route.js
model() {
  return this.get('store').findAll('route');
}
```

If you want to create a new record here as well, you can do that like this:

```
// route.js
model() {
  this.get('store').createRecord('route');
  return this.get('store').findAll('route');
}
```

The result of the `model` hook is passed to the `setupController` method. This method is fired automatically, and it is what builds the controller object. The controller is what communicates the model to your view.  This is what it does by default:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
}
```

You shouldn't have to overwrite anything here, but it's good to know when the controller is created for us.

Now we can add this computed property to our controller. By default, you most likely don't have a controller.js file. You can generate one with Ember-CLI: `ember g controller <route-name>`

Since `model` was passed to our controller, we can add a computed property that filters the model:

```
// controller.js
routes: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'isNew', false)
```

This will be an array of all the `route` records that are no "new."  Now our view should have access to `routes`.

```
//route.hbs
<form>
//some fields
//and a select-component:
{{my-select
    selected=model.takeover
    options=routes
}}
</form>
```

I'm not sure what `model.takover` refers to. But if you want to get the record that `isNew` you could similarly filter those records to return only the one that is new.

Comment: could you clearly write what should go to model and what to controller, please?

Comment: Updated. Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. My aim is to usethe most Ember-way. Sometimes it is hard for me because there many possibilitys and even the guides changed in the last months. I understand your way and it makes sense. But what would you think of filtering the routes in the afterModel hook and not in the controller? Model.takeover is a one-to-one relationship to another route and this is why I have to filter the routes, takeover cant be the same route itself

Comment: @BennyAlex Traditionally, you see the afterModel hook reserved for actions that need to happen based on the model that is loaded.  The result of the data here is not passed to your controller, though. So if you cleaned the data there, it would not be reflected in your view.  If you want to filter your model in the `route.js` file and not go through the controller, you should do it in the `setupController` hook.  `afterModel` does not return any data.